# Exporting a music expression to be included in another file

Tags: lilypond

I'm working on engraving an orchestral work, and currently I'm using the standard note file and layout file project structure. However, for parts this requires the addition of individual files for each of the parts. This makes me curious about whether Lilypond has an 'export' function? For example in Javascript you can add `export { variables, classes }` at the bottom of one file, and then if you import it into another, only the code labeled for export is actually imported. For lilypond, I can imagine a part file having the music expression as a variable, as well as the `\layout`, `\score`, and `\header`. Then, the music expression is exported to be included in the score file, so that the formatting options don't conflict. Is this a feature that lilypond has? Or is this more fundamentally messy?

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently implemented, although it [has been discussed](https://gitlab.com/lilypond/lilypond/-/issues/6475) in the past.